# Failed to change the text of a titlebar in a container with sencha touch 2.1

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to create an application with users login and logout. When the user logs in ,the system will store the user information such as username,sessionid into the localstorage and then go to the index page. The index page has a titlebar with username on the left and a button to log out.But it failed to get the data stored in the localstorage that was stored when a user logs in when the index page appears.
My code is as below:

index page:

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend : 'Ext.Panel',
    id : 'myPanel',
    config : {
        xtype : 'panel',
        layout : 'vbox',
        height : '100%',
        width : '100%',
        items : [ 
            {
                xtype : 'titlebar',
                docked : 'top',
                title : 'my panel',
                items : [ 
                    {   
                        align : 'left',
                        id : 'portal-username',
                        text : 'qq' //i used localStorage.getItem（'userName'） first，but not as good.
                    },   
                    {
                        align : 'right',
                        text : 'log out',
                        listeners : {
                            tap : function(){
                                var userName=null;var rememberPassword=null;var password=null;

                                if(userName=Ext.getCmp('userName'))userName.setValue('');
                                if(password=Ext.getCmp('password'))password.setValue('');
                                if(rememberPassword=Ext.getCmp('rememberPassword'))rememberPassword.setChecked(false);
                                //localstorage
                                localStorage.removeItem('userName','');
                                localStorage.removeItem('password','');
                                localStorage.removeItem('SessionId','');
                                localStorage.removeItem('rememberPassword','');


                                    var oldp=Ext.getCmp('loginPanel');if(oldp)oldp.destroy();
                                    var newActivePanel = Ext.create('MyApp.view.LoginPanel');
                                    Ext.Viewport.add(newActivePanel);
                                    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(newActivePanel,{type:'slide',direction:'left'});
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

part of login panel:

```
                            items : [
                                    {
                                        xtype : 'button',
                                        text : 'login',
                                        ui : 'action',
                                        handler : function() {



                                            var userName = Ext.getCmp('userName').getValue();
                                            var password = Ext.getCmp('password').getValue();
                                            var rememberPassword = Ext.getCmp('rememberPassword').getChecked()+ '';

                                            if(!userName||!password){
                                                Ext.Msg.alert('prompt','login failure，try again！',Ext.emptyFn);
                                            }
                                            else Ext.Ajax.request({
                                                        url : remoteServer,
                                                        params : {
                                                            loginName: userName,
                                                            passWord : password,
                                                            SessionId : localStorage.getItem('SessionId');
                                                        },
                                                        method : 'POST',
                                                        callback : function(options,success,response) {
                                                            if (success) {
                                                                var result = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText.trim());
                                                                var status = result.status;
                                                                if (status == 'success') {
                                                                        if (rememberPassword == 'true')
                                                                            localStorage.setItem('rememberPassword',rememberPassword);

                                                                        localStorage.setItem('userName',userName);
                                                                        localStorage.setItem('password',password);
                                                                        localStorage.setItem('SessionId',result.SessionId);



                                                                        var oldp=Ext.getCmp('MyPanel');if(oldp)oldp.destroy();
                                                                        var newActivePanel = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyPanel');
                                                                        Ext.Viewport.add(newActivePanel);
                                                                        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(newActivePanel,{type:'slide',direction:'left'});

                                                                } else {
                                                                    localStorage.setItem('userName','');
                                                                    localStorage.setItem('password','');
                                                                    localStorage.setItem('JSessionId','');
                                                                    localStorage.setItem('rememberPassword','');


                                                                    Ext.Msg.alert('prompt','login failure，try again！',Ext.emptyFn);
                                                                }
                                                            } else {
                                                                Ext.Msg.alert('prompt','login failure，try again！',Ext.emptyFn);
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
```

Below is my controller :

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController',
    {
        extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
        id : 'MyController',
        config : {
            control : {
                MyPanel : {
                    show : 'panelActive'
                },
            },
            refs : {
                MyPanel : '#myPanel'
            }
        }//config
        ,panelActive : function(){
            Ext.getCmp('portal-username').setText(localStorage.getItem('userName'));
        }
});
```

Comment: Where do you setting the username in titlebar ?

Comment: @ Viswa   Thanks for your reply. I have re-edited it,Please see the changes.

Comment: Did you checked in browser localStorage resource ? and What value you getting from localStorage.getItem('userName') ?

Comment: i chencked,it is what i want.So i guess the definition may read the localstorage before i put data in it

Comment: May be.. just do 'alert(localStorage.getItem('userName')); within panelActive function' and see what you getting in alert

Comment: i missed that animateActiveItem line.. see i updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

After Following line

`Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(newActivePanel,{type:'slide',direction:'left'});`

in login handler function just set the username using

`Ext.getCmp('portal-username').setText(userName);`

Comment: i got : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setText' of undefined

Comment: @gabrielaflext i missed that animateActiveItem line.. see i updated the answer